# Potential dangerous request, hide error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to check the security of my MVC application. When I try to input html or javascript it gives an error: Potential dangerous request.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (TEKST="<html><b>joo</b></ht...").
Description: Request Validation has detected a potentially dangerous client input value, and processing of the request has been aborted. This value may indicate an attempt to compromise the security of your application, such as a cross-site scripting attack. To allow pages to override application request validation settings, set the requestValidationMode attribute in the httpRuntime configuration section to requestValidationMode="2.0". Example: <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />. After setting this value, you can then disable request validation by setting validateRequest="false" in the Page directive or in the <pages> configuration section. However, it is strongly recommended that your application explicitly check all inputs in this case. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=153133.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (TEKST="<html><b>joo</b></ht...").

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

This looks good, it is not possible to inject HTML or JavaScript. But the thing that I do not like, the users will see my version of ASP.net and everything.

How can I remove this error and give just a message with: I don't like your input or whatever.

I have tried to do this but this is not working:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create(int album_id)
{
    ViewBag.album_id = album_id;
    return View();
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(REVIEW model)
{
    string txt = null;
    try
    {
        txt = model.TEKST;
    }
    catch (System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException)
    {
        txt = "errorrr";
    }


    return RedirectToAction("Add", new { tekst = txt, album_id=model.ALBUM_ID});
}
```

SOLUTION:
See Nudier's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can handle errors within your application in the following way

**1.** Setting the CustomErros mode section in your Web.Config file of your application

**This the lists of options the mode attribute can accept.**

**RemoteOnly:** Generic error pages are shown for remote users. Rich error pages are shown for
local requests (requests that are made from the current computer). This is the
default setting.

**Off:** Rich error pages are shown for all users, regardless of the source of the request.
This setting is helpful in many development scenarios but should not be used in
a deployed application.

**On:** Generic error pages are shown for all users, regardless of the source of the
request. This is the most secure option.

```
     <System.Web>
      //map all the erros presented in the application to the error.aspx webpage
     <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect ="~/error.aspx" />
    <System.Web>
```

**2.** throught Global.asax file in the Application_Error function

```
     //handle all the errors presented in the application
      void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e){  
     Server.Tranfer("error.aspx");
    }
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: I recommend the first method. It's possible to temporarily disable the redirect via the first method by modifying your web.config. The same is not as easy in the second.

Comment: This is also in my config file: <pages validateRequest="false" .... So I shouldn't see this error page at all, do I?

Comment: your right @MikeBantegui the first method is always the safe and versatile way to do it.

Comment: @user1408786 , I have updated the answer with a better explanation about how you can configure the CustomErrors Section.

Comment: Thank you very much! This made it clear for me :) Edit: to make it even more useful for other users, could you change Mode to mode? It doesn't accept Mode with uppercase M.